# Graficar punto distancia

Tags: python

Hola estoy creando un programita en donde estoy graficando funciones de geometría con la librería mathplotlib, logre graficar funciones, pero no logro hacer que grafique la distancia de un punto a una recta, tengo creada la ecuación de la recta, tengo el punto y la ecuación que me da la distancia pero, no logro crear la rayita que una el punto con mi recta :/, de antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda.

dejo el código de lo que llevo y que si funciona.

```
import math
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import pyplot 


def ecuacion_recta(m,x,b):
   return m*x+b

def recta_punto(A,B,C,x,y):
   return abs(A*x+B*y+C)/math.sqrt(A**2 + B**2) 



x = range(-10, 10)

pyplot.plot(x, [ecuacion_recta(3,i,4) for i in x])
pyplot.plot(-1,2, marker="o", color ="red")


pyplot.axhline(0, color="black")
pyplot.axvline(0, color="black")

pyplot.xlim(-11, 11)
pyplot.ylim(-11, 11)

pyplot.show()
```